# Tell screen reader to stop talking when media is playing

Tags: accessibility, data-visualization, html5-audio, wai-aria, screen-readers

As a small experiment I made [a time series chart that also has an audio component](http://bl.ocks.org/aholachek/6e18a82c0f0ada144b854f788c07d7a4), so that blind users could in theory learn about the data by listening to the chart. The audio is generated with the HTML5 Audio API and it is triggered to play by pressing a simple button.

When I try accessing the page with the screen reader Voiceover, after a few seconds of the audio playing after the button click, the screen reader announces: "You are currently on a header level 2, inside HTML content" which drowns out the final half of the audio. Is there some kind of ARIA state or other markup I could use to tell the screen reader to be silent until the end of the 10 second clip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (afaik) stop screenreaders from speaking with any scripting, and to do so would likely cause problems in any case.

I think it's great that you're offering the option of having this audio component, and I suspect that most\all screenreader users will be aware that pressing ctrl (for JAWS\NVDA, and maybe VoiceOver) will stop the screenreader speech and allow them to listen to any provided audio.

However, it would be useful (and indeed a requirement under WCAG) to provide a text alternativefor the chart . Perhaps this could the simply be the script which is being announced via the HTML5 audio API? This would be suited for deaf\blind users, accessing content via braille display.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the ctrl command to silence the reader, if people can just do that, it's definitely sufficient. Regarding your last point, below the chart I also include an accessible sortable, filterable table of the dataset since I think that is a more traditional way to give screen readers access.

Comment: JAWS, NVDA, Narrator, VoiceOver all use the ctrl key to stop the screen reader from talking. More [commands for each in this handy testing guide](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2015/01/basic-screen-reader-commands-for-accessibility-testing/).